# create file in cache

Tags: java, caching

My requirement is such, I don't have a target file located physically on my drive to write outputstream in it. So, is it possible to create a file in the cache itself?  Using Java.

Comment: what do you mean by cache? an in-memory file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you refering to creating a temporary file? Try

```
File.createTempFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want is [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) which allows you to write to a stream in memory instead of writing to disk.

If you are referring to the CPU or disk caches, can you say why, and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't have write permission in the server. In ByteArrayInputStream I am getting a pdf file, this file i need to display in a popup, using as suggested by you from memory.

Comment: How are you intending to display the PDF?  You need to use a way of passing the file your viewer supports.  Are you sure you cannot write the the temporary area? (This is writeable on almost all systems) `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`

Answer (score 0):

The cache is not program accessible, it uses a replacement policy to store data local to the processor in order to reduce the number of relatively costly fetches from memory.

I suspect you actually want to write to memory, under a linux enviroment you can do this using shared memory `/dev/shm`, it is a part of the system memory which has been mapped onto a filesystem. For an example how this is combined with `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` have a look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/1185555)

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of memory mapped files , try this

```
//: c12:LargeMappedFiles.java
// Creating a very large file using mapping.
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class LargeMappedFiles {
  static int length = 0x8FFFFFF; // 128 Mb
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MappedByteBuffer out = 
      new RandomAccessFile("test.dat", "rw").getChannel()
      .map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      out.put((byte)'x');
    System.out.println("Finished writing");
    for(int i = length/2; i < length/2 + 6; i++)
      System.out.print((char)out.get(i));
  }
} ///:~
```

the sample is from [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm)